# Regular Expression in mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: javascript

Below is the regular expression for `mm/dd/yyyy` format. BUT the expression is giving true for `mmddyyyy` format also. It should return false without `'/'`.

Anyone can change it to the required regex?

```
/^(((0[13-9]|1[012])[-/]?(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)|(0[13578]|1[02])[-/]?31|02[-/]?(0[1-9]|
1[0-9]|2[0-8]))[-/]?[0-9]{4}|02[-/]?29[-/]?([0-9]{2}(([2468][048]|[02468][48])|[13579][26])|
([13579][26]|[02468][048]|0[0-9]|1[0-6])00))$/
```

Comment: replace every `[-/]`? with `[-/]`

Comment: /^(((0[13-9]|1[012])[-/](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)|(0[13578]|1[02])[-/]31|02[-/](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))[-/][0-9]{4}|02[-/]29[-/]([0-9]{2}(([2468][048]|[02468][48])|[13579][26])|([13579][26]|[02468][048]|0[0-9]|1[0-6])00))$/

(It's also a regexp for a lot more dates like dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the regex you want

```
/^(((0[13-9]|1[012])[-/](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)|(0[13578]|1[02])[-/]31|02[-/](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))[-/][0-9]{4}|02[-/]29[-/]([0-9]{2}(([2468][048]|[02468][48])|[13579][26])|([13579][26]|[02468][048]|0[0-9]|1[0-6])00))$/
```

`[-/]?` will check for 0 or 1 occurrence of '/' in your string. `[-/]` will check exactly 1 occurrence instead.

Comment: this is what I needed. Thanks alot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegEx, its working

```js
var date = "21062016";//"21/06/2016"; 
var rgexp = /(^(((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[/](0[1-9]|1[012]))|((29|30|31)[/](0[13578]|1[02]))|((29|30)[/](0[4,6,9]|11)))[/](19|[2-9][0-9])\d\d$)|(^29[/]02[/](19|[2-9][0-9])(00|04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)$)/;
var validate = rgexp.test(date);
alert(validate);
```